# Figures are showing at the last page when trying to show two images in two column format

Tags: floats

I am trying to show two images, each in one column at the top of a page. But the figures being sent to the last page and also they are showing vertically placed in a single column

```
begin{figure*}[h]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{rearr1.png}
\caption{Rearrangement 1}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{rearr2.png}
    \caption{Rearrangement 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

How can I show two independent images, each in one column in a two column format file, at the top of the page.

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full minimal example others can test as is. You can use images from the `mwe` package (they are listed here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe), then you'll be using images that everyone have access to. Your choice of class and preamble will affect the outcome of this sniplet, therefore the sniplet it self is not enough for us to help

Comment: `figure*` doesn't have an `h` option so `\begin{figure*}[h]` prevents `t` (top of page) and prevents `p` (page on its own) so means that the figure is not allowd anywhere so it will be held to the end of the document or `\clearpage` and then dumped out as an emergency recovery. Only add placement options to figures when you really need to control the placement.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the placement options but the images are still showing on top of each other in the left column

Comment: you have a paragraph break between the minipages forcing them to be one above the other. They are positioned like letters, use `\end{minipage}\hfill \begin{minipage}` not a blank line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot, that worked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please consider turning your comments into an answer. Users are, I think, more likely to look at questions that have answers, even if comments provide a solution.

Comment: @PeterWilson sure although it's probably a duplicate.I'll have look